# Customizing Trust Pilot Widget CSS

Tags: css

I've added a [TrustPilot Widget](http://help.dandomain.dk/Webshop6/DK/HTML/7.11_Trustpilot.htm) to my Website.

I want to overwrite the current stylesheet being imported from TP. I thought I'd just add a class around the div and then style it in the css with the use of !important however all attempts have failed.

I was wondering if anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to manipulate it through javascript as they write the sprite image in the element itself, witch overrides any other style rule.

a simple jQuery

```
$("#tp_widget div").attr("style", "");
```

here's a live demo on how to custom the top header: http://jsbin.com/usadit/3/

and you can edit it through the /edit url as: http://jsbin.com/usadit/3/edit

Comment: No need to say thanks, it's agains the rules in Stackoverflow... you should **upvote questions** when they're the one you wanted and worked, as well make it the **correct answer** if it's the answer that made your troubles go away :)

Comment: There's no output in the jsbin

Comment: @tarekfellah this is an answer from **2012** ... fell free to answer now or edit my answer...